# Is the behavior of an array iterator defined if the underlying collection is added to during iteration?

Tags: javascript, iterator, generator

So I have a situation where I have a generator function that should be returning values from an array, but the array is being populated in the same loop that is consuming the output of the generator.

The specific scenario is a generator to return the key sequence for an autokey cipher, where each newly-decoded character is appended to the end of the cipher key.  My implementation works, but I am not certain if it's guaranteed to work, or if this is an example of undefined behavior that happens to be working in my favor.

Essentially, must the code below always print "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", or would it be valid for an implementation to print "a", "b", "c", "undefined", "undefined"?  I'm always leery about modifying a collection being iterated upon.

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
let iter = function*() { yield* a; }();
console.log(iter.next().value);  // "a"
console.log(iter.next().value);  // "b"
a.push("d");
a.push("e");
console.log(iter.next().value);  // "c"
console.log(iter.next().value);  // "d" - but is this guaranteed?
console.log(iter.next().value);  // "e" - or is it?
```

**Edited**: Changed the title from talking about "generators" to "iterators" to more accurately reflect the real meat of the question

Comment: I think you'd need to make a copy of a at the start of your generator, then `yield *` to the copy.

Comment: Yes, ES6 specifies the behaviour of `@@iterator()` for all collections to handle mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to *ES6 & Beyond*, by Kyle Simpson, p. 103, `yield *` takes an *iterable*, and "invokes that iterable's iterator".  So you are really asking about **iterable** behavior, not **generator** behavior.

I had trouble finding the official spec for how an array's iterator reacts when the underlying array is modified, but I have to assume that such a basic feature is implemented correctly - i.e., per your experiment, the new array elements get included in the iterable.  Unless, of course, you are using IE6.  :-)

Therefore, if you want your generator to only include the original elements of `a[]`, you'd have to make a copy.  e.g.

```
let iter = function*(a) {
  let copy = Array.from(a);
  yield * copy;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction on terminology!  You're correct, my question was really about iterable behavior.  I'm actually getting the results I want (I want it to yield all elements including newly-added ones), I had been curious on whether that behavior was well defined by the spec or not.  From Bergi's comment, and now that I actually searched for the right thing (Array iterators, not generator behavior), I found that %ArrayIteratorPrototype%.next() should always evaluate the current length (http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-%arrayiteratorprototype%.next)